# Overuse of try and except in python code when using regex

Tags: python

I think i am over using try and except in my code. It's pretty much everywhere, where i have regexp matching. If it does not find the regex, it throws an exception, so i use the try and except to capture this to prevent my code from crashing. Example of what i'm talking about.

```
try:
    Output = "John Bob Charlie"
    match = re.search(r'John', Output, re.M|re.I) #use try/except, to stop unmatch causing crash
except:
    print("Darn, no John")
```

Is there a better way of doing this or is this normal?? I'm new to Python and coming from Perl, a simple

```
if match{
print('we have found John')
}
```

Was all i needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: re.search returns None if it is not found ... it doesnt throw an exception ... so you can indeed just do `if match:`  https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/EmbarrassedHeavyScientist

Comment: using try / except like that is bad practice in python. multiple ways to iterate and look for words. using for loops is the easiest..

Comment: @E.Gertz - That's a broad claim! Regular expressions are a normal and pythonic way to search strings.

Comment: @tdelaney EGertz didnt say anything about regex... he was talking about this weird `try/cache` that doesnt do what OP thinks it does (I think thats what he meant at least)

Comment: How best to use exceptions will create vigorous conversation around the water cooler. For regex, not matching a string is a normal thing and won't raise an exception. If you've got a zillion exception handlers then maybe its time to rethink how you are handling errors. Exceptions are best when fewer exception handlers are used over broader sections of code. If 10 handlers all do the same thing, then maybe 1 handler further up the stack is a better choice.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - then what does "multiple ways to iterate and look for words" mean? Its not that the example is bad practice, its a bug.

Comment: Its probably a better question for @E.Gertz ... but i think E.Gertz imagines one file with a bunch of these try/excepts looking for different matches, and is advising to use a loop for that (of coarse I could easily be reading too much into it... and it really doesnt address the actual question from OP)

Comment: I wasnt meaning anything specific about regex, more specifically about try / cache like @JoranBeasley helped me explain further down the discussion. I was imagining a file with multiple try`s and looping through the different words / sentences that are needed to be matched...

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use an if statement to check whether there is any match

```
Output = "John Bob Charlie"
match = re.search(r'John', Output, re.M|re.I) #use try/except, to stop unmatch causing crash

if match:
    # Do Something here 
else:
    print("Darn, no John")
```

You could refer the regex documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) where a simple if statement is used

Answer (score 1):

I would say use exception for the cases where there is an exception (something unknown or unexpected). For example, you are calling an external API to fetch some data and the API throws an exception.

In your case, you should just go with:

```
if not match:
    return ('Darn, no John')
# here you can do whatever you want to do with Output variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work, because `re.search` returns `None` if the expression is not found.

Instead of try-except use `if`:

```
Output = "John Bob Charlie"
match = re.search(r'John', Output, re.M|re.I)
if not match:
    print("Darn, no John")
```